# When I tried upload image to database I got this error

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I'm beginner in Laravel and I found this code (I don't know ajax/jquery). When I try upload image to my database I got this error. How can I fix it? Can I upload title and image at the same time with this code?

**Error is:
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null**

**My controller is:**

```
public function imagePost(request $request){

        $request->validate([
            
            'title' => ['string', 'max:128'],
            'first_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:4096',
            
            
        ]);

        if ($files = $request->file('first_photo')) {
            
            $fileName =  "first_photo-".time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image->public_path('/images/posts/posts_first_images/', $fileName);
            
            $image = new Image;
            $image->image = $fileName;
            $image->save();

            return Response()->json([
                "first_photo" => $fileName
            ], Response::HTTP_OK);
 
        }


        title = $request->title;
        $first_photo = $request->first_photo; 



        $save = Post::create([
            'title' => $title,
            'first_image' => $first_photo,

            
        ]);

     

        if($save){
            return back()->with('success','success');
        }else{
            return back()->with('error','error');
        }
```

**My blade is:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('imagePost')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_image_form" >

                    @csrf


                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
                          <img id="image_preview_container" 
                              alt="preview image" style="max-height: 150px;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="file" name="first_photo" placeholder="Choose image" >
                          </div>
                      </div>
                        
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input class="form-control" maxlength="128" name='title' placeholder="Title" required="" autofocus="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
              </form>
```

**And my ajax/jquery (or javascript really I don't know I'm really rookie)**

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function (e) {
       
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
       });
      
       $('#first_photo').change(function(){
               
        let reader = new FileReader();
    
        reader.onload = (e) => { 
    
          $('#image_preview_container').attr('src', e.target.result); 
        }
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); 
      
       });
      
       $('#upload_image_form').submit(function(e) {
    
         e.preventDefault();
      
         var formData = new FormData(this);
      
         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: "{{ route('imagePost')}}",
            data: formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: (data) => {
               this.reset();
               alert('Image has been uploaded successfully');
            },
            error: function(data){
               console.log(data);
             }
           });
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```php
$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

to

```php
$request->file('first_photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

note in your *blade* you name it 'first_photo'

```html
<input type="file" name="first_photo" placeholder="Choose image" >
```

so always check both input name and file parameter, names must be same.

### How to save it?

```php
// Move the image to public folder inside images folder:
$request()->file('first_photo')->move(public_path('images/posts/posts_first_images/'), $filename);
```

Comment: thank you. now i got this error
" Call to a member function public_path() on null "

Comment: i update the answer check it out. try not to call it directly. call it with the file methode.

Comment: yes the names of both are the same.but still getting this error

Comment: did you replace $request->image->public_path with $request->file('first_photo')->public_path or not, i update the answer again, please check it and tell if it worked?

Comment: now i got this 
"Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::public_path does not exist."

Comment: me too now i got that you call this method and you don't store it in any variable, so delete it you don't even need it.

Comment: so how can I save it?

Comment: by moving the image to public folder then save image in the DATABASE. check the answer again :)

Comment: i got this error :( 
" Object of type Illuminate\Http\Request is not callable "
i'm really beginner i don't know how can I fix like this errors i'm sorry :(

Comment: try to add include it at top `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` we are all beginner, we try to be better programmers, so keep try untill it works *happy coding :)*